# Brainfuck тригонометрия

Tags: brainfuck

Как вобще можно в БФ сотворить tgx

Comment: Вы таки желаете fuck свой brain? Успехов.

Comment: А чем отличается вычисление тригонометрических функций на BF от такового в любом языке с бедной стандартной библиотекой? Ничем: считайте руками.

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже решили как будете представлять числа с плавающей точкой?

Для вычисления есть 2 простых способа:

1. [Ряд Тейлора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)
2. Предрасчитаные таблицы + [интерполяция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 0):

Ряд тейлора в сумму разложить. Хотя мне говорили что это неэффективно.